# removing duplicates from a nested/2D array (removing the nested duplicate element)

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, duplicates

So that:

```
array = [[12,13,24],[24,22,11],[11,44,55]]
```

would return:

```
cleanedArray = [[12,13,24],[22,11],[44,55]]
```

I'm surprised not to have found this answered here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var array = [[12,13,24],[24,22,11],[11,44,55]];
var output = [];
var found = {};
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    output.push([]);
    for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        if (!found[array[i][j]]) {
            found[array[i][j]] = true; 
            output[i].push(array[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

console.log(output);
```

Comment: If modifying the original is OK, duplicates can be removed with *splice* to avoid making a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a function that does this for just two-dimensional arrays?  If so, then I think this would work:

```
Array.prototype.clean = function()
{
    var found = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
    {
        for(var j = 0; j < this[i].length; j++)
        {
            if(found.indexOf(this[i][j]) != -1)
            {
                this[i].splice(j, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                found.push(this[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    return this;
};
```

If it's just a one-dimensional array you're looking for, then:

```
Array.prototype.clean = function()
{
    var found = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
    {
        if(found.indexOf(this[i]) != -1)
        {
            this.splice(i, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            found.push(this[i]);
        }
    }

    return this;
};
```

this would work.  If you're doing either of those, then do .clean() on your array to clean it up.

Comment: When *splice* is called, the remaining members are shifted one lower in index so the above will skip the next member each time it splices one. It matters if there are adjacent duplicates. That can be solved by either going backwards through the array or decrementing the counter each time *splice* is called.

Answer (score 0):

A simple function that modifies the original array is:

```
function removeDups(a) {
  var item, j, found = {};

  for (var i=0, iLen=a.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    item = a[i];
    j=item.length;

    while (j--) {
      found.hasOwnProperty(item[j])? item.splice(j,1) : found[item[j]] = '';
    }
  }
  return a;
}
```